# How to Get Device Name of my Raspberry Pi2

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, c#

I am using Raspberry Pi2 with Windows 10 IoT Core OS, I am developing an UWP app in that I want to get Device Name of my Raspberry Pi 2. Can any one help me how to get it?

I tried using the following code but dont know is it correct way or not

```
public string GetDeviceName()
    {
        List<string> IpAddress = new List<string>();
        var Hosts = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames().ToList();
        foreach (var Host in Hosts)
        {
            string deviceName = Host.DisplayName;
            return deviceName;
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: it's C#.Net @v7d8dpo4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it this way and it works very well:

```
private string GetHostName()
    {
        foreach (Windows.Networking.HostName name in Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
        {
            if (Windows.Networking.HostNameType.DomainName == name.Type)
            {
                return name.DisplayName;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use one of these lines for getting device name. Probably last line you're searching for...

- `System.Environment.MachineName`
- `HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName`
- `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()`

**Update:**

```
Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation eas = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
var dialog = new MessageDialog(eas.FriendlyName);
dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but sadly the lines you mentioned are not useful for an UWP app.

Comment: Updated my entry. Tried on Windows 10 and gave my machine name. You may also look another properties of EasClientDeviceInformation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation