# How to register new devices with the Azure IoT Hub/How can I send new sensors' data to my IoT Hub without editing my code?

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot

I am working on IoT Technology. I have doubt as I developed an IoT Project which is sending different sensors data to the [Azure IoT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/iot-hub/).

Next I bought one more Raspberry Pi 2 device and deployed my application into it. This new device can’t send sensors data to my IoT hub because, in my application, I have written a connection string for only one device.

So, there is only one chance is to edit my code but I want, without disturbing my existing code, to register my new device with my IoT hub. After deploying my application into this Pi I will then send the sensors data to IoT hub.

Please tell me how I can achieve the above scenario.

Comment: Could you confirm that the hub you're talking about is the [Azure IoT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/iot-hub/)?

Comment: Yes, I used the Azure IoT Hub

Comment: I think I can solve this if I can figure out how to get a unique identifier from the Pi using C#. That's proving trickier than I'd hoped. I'll update if I find anything.

Comment: I think this link will help to get the Device Id and name using C#.
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45574/how-to-get-device-name-of-my-raspberry-pi2?rq=1, Please tell me how to get my scenario.

Comment: That might work for retrieving the device *name*, but the name isn't necessarily unique, and can normally be set by the user. What I think we can do to address your problem is to generate or retrieve some kind of UUID which is specific to that Pi, and is unchangeable throughout the Pi's lifetime. A CPU ID number, a Windows license key - something along those lines.

Comment: Look at this answer http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/52009/894 to help you get an ID that you then pass into Azure IoT to identify the device uniquely

Comment: Using the MAC code should identify the network interface uniquely but it may not be static, perhaps particularly on the Pi where there's more of a tendency for people to move USB WiFi dongles about. If you switched from WiFi to ethernet then regenerated an ID from the first available interface you'd get a different MAC value. If that was used as an Azure hub device ID I think that would generate a new device, rather than associate with an existing one.